# Installing docker from a package

Tags: ubuntu, docker, installation

I am trying to install docker manually following these instructions: 
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package

The first step says to download `.deb` file from here:
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/stable/

There are only contents-* files and binary-*. I don't see any `.deb` files.
Is there any other place where I can find `.deb` for docker?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can check https://pkgs.org/download/docker
You can check debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a mistake on the path. In the documentation he says it very clearly *choose your Ubuntu version, browse to **pool/stable*** You didn't enter the **pool** directory. You went straight to the **stable** directory.

Try this: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/

You will be able to see the .deb you are looking for.

Comment: I treated the documentation like a person *"he says it very clearly"*. That's because for me the official documentation is very important that I treat **her** like a person.